# How to use Pageant under SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, git, pageant

When I turn on my server I want the SYSTEM to load Pageant and some keys, because a build application might later be activated also with SYSTEM rights. And that build application should use the keys to get access to my remote Git repository. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Run the Pageant the same way you run the "build application".

Comment: I could but what happens if I activate the application twice, then pageant will also be activated twice. Will that do?

Answer (score 0):

Run the Pageant the same way you run the "build application".

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" C:\path\to\key.ppk
```

---

If you run it again, nothing happens. If Pageant is already running in the session, the second instance just instructs the existing instance to load the keys. If the same keys are already loaded, nothing happens.

Comment: That will not work. pageant stalls when run from a system account.